# Error Code : 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Tags: mysql

I want to use ids from query on table mktplace_olap to DAYOFWEEK() function from inventory_log.
**The problem is** there is `no 'id' column` in mktplace_olap and i don't want to join these two tables.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ol.sof_shipped_at_date,ol.order_creation_date) as totDays,

    /* DAYOFWEEK(ADDDATE(ol.order_creation_date,id)) as dayOfWeek*/count(*)
     FROM dwa_olap_mktplace.mktplace_olap ol 
    WHERE  did in (select il.id from mktplace_catalog.inventory_log il) and id  <= DATEDIFF(ol.sof_shipped_at_date,ol.order_creation_date)     
    AND DAYOFWEEK(ADDDATE(ol.order_creation_date,did))  IN (1);
```

Comment: Where is the variable `did` which appears in your `WHERE` clause defined?

Comment: I's not the mktplace_olap table mysql is complaining about, but the inventory_log table. The latter one does not seem to have an id column either. Fix the query in the in().

Comment: I was making some changes and provided the query which is edited, kindly refer id in place of did.

Comment: I want to use 'id' from inventory_log as id is column containing numbers as 1,2,3,.... and so on, i want to use this series to increase date in DAYOFWEEK() function, but id is not present in mktplace_olap.

Comment: here "id  <= DATEDIFF(ol.sof_shipped_at_date,ol.order_creation_date)" id will be used of mktplace_olap table and it seems you are using query from some other db than dwa_olap_mktplace, so first "use dwa_olap_mktplace" then execute query or use as "ol.id  <= DATEDIFF(ol.sof_shipped_at_date,ol.order_creation_date)"

Comment: as you are using 2 db here in query so for safe side always use aliases with all fields.

Comment: I tried removing "ol.id <= DATEDIFF(ol.sof_shipped_at_date,ol.order_creation_date)", still same problem.